# From where can I download NCEP Vertical wind?

Tags: atmosphere, wind, earth-observation, reanalysis

I want to download Vertical Velocity (Pa/sec) data either in era interim or NCAR data from a website. Please I need the link.

Answer (score 1):

The variable for vertical velocity in NCEP-NCAR is omega, dp/dt or change of pressure with time. Go to https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanalysis.html and type "omega" in the search variable field to look for the specific time resolution data you want to download.

[image]